# Opening Popup Window is not working in firefox and google chrome

Tags: asp.net, javascript, popupwindow

I want to open a popupwindow (with close button only) when the user clicks a button and the parent window should be disabled until the popup window closed. For that I'm using the following code

```
function popup_window(url) {

     popupwin = window.showModalDialog(url,null,'height=20,width=150,status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no');     
     }
```

Anyhow, this code is working perfectly in IE. But, I hav two problems.
In firefox, it is not opening with the size I've mentioned in the script. It is opening in full size. And In Google Chrome, parent window is not getting disabled.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax of the args](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.showModalDialog) is different. For example:

```
window.showModalDialog(url, null, 
"dialogwidth: 150; dialogheight: 20; resizable: no")
```

Comment: I tried.. Working properly in firefox. But, now IE is getting too large for that size..