# Opening modal dialog window is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popupwindow

Response To:
[Opening Popup Window is not working in firefox and google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144921/opening-popup-window-is-not-working-in-firefox-and-google-chrome)

Hi,I have similar code in above question.My code works fine in IE.

```
this.parent.window.showModalDialog('Counter.aspx', '', 
'dialogHeight:170px;dialogWidth:150px;status:no;scroll:no;edge:sunken;toolbar:0;center:on;help:off;unadorned:yes;');
```

What can i do about this code in order to open this window in Google Chrome browser ?

Thanks for any assistance 
Myra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

showModalDialog works in chrome(its not truly modal though). the problem could be that it is blocking them. Chrome's minimalistic design doesnt even tell you that some times. try adding an exception for you current website.

you can find it under -

Options->**Under The Hood** Tab-> **Content Settings** Button -> **Popups** Tab -> **Exceptions** button

Comment: So there is no way by code to handle my window event.It's just browser setting to add.

Comment: if popups are blocked there is nothing that you can do from code to forcefully open a dialog as far i know